NATS Jetstream consumer concurrency
My typescript application is made of several projects that all have different kinds of microservices;
server : REST API that publishes messages to NATS for other services to update a (mongo) DB
synchronizer : Process that consumes NATS messages and update the DB.
My problem is I can run multiple instances of the same synchronizers. In this case, I have multiple consumers of the same kind that are bound to the same stream.
I want my pull consumers to consume the same streams but not the same messages.
For now, my Consumer class looks like this :
import { AckPolicy, Codec, ConsumerConfig, DeliverPolicy, JetStreamClient, JetStreamManager, JsMsg, JSONCodec, ReplayPolicy, StringCodec } from "nats";

interface IEvent<T extends any> {
  subject: string;
  data: T
}

const createConsumerOptions = (serviceName: string): ConsumerConfig => {
  return {
    ack_policy: AckPolicy.Explicit,
    deliver_policy: DeliverPolicy.New,
    replay_policy: ReplayPolicy.Instant,
    ack_wait: 1000,
    flow_control: true,
    max_ack_pending: 5,
    max_waiting: 1,
    durable_name: serviceName // <- Example: "Auth-Service"
  };
};

export const initConsumer = async (js: JetStreamClient, serviceName: string, subject: string) => {
  const jsm = await js.jetstreamManager();
  if (!jsm) throw new Error("JetstreamManager Error");

  await initStream(jsm, subject);

  const options = createConsumerOptions(serviceName);

  await jsm.consumers.add(subject, options).catch((ex) => console.log(ex));
  let result = await js.consumers.get(subject, options);

  if (!result) throw new Error("Consumer Error");

  return result;
};

export const initStream = async (jsm: JetStreamManager, subject: string) => {
  const stream = await jsm.streams.find(subject).catch((ex) => console.log(ex));
  if (!stream) await jsm.streams.add({ name: subject.toString(), subjects: [subject] }).catch((ex) => console.log(ex));
};

export abstract class Consumer<T extends IEvent<any>> {
  abstract subject: T["subject"];
  abstract onMessage(data: T["data"], msg: JsMsg): Promise<any>;

  protected _client: Client;

  constructor(client: Client) {
    this._client = client;
  }

  async listen() {
    const js = await this._client.Connection?.jetstream();
    if (!js) throw new Error("Jetstream Error");

    const consumer = await initConsumer(js, this._client.ServiceName, this.subject);
    const msgs = await consumer.consume();
    for await (const msg of msgs) {
      const data = JSONCodec().decode(msg.data)

      try {
        await this.onMessage(data, msg);
        msg.ack();
      } catch (err) {
        msg.nack();
      }
    }
  }
}


For now replaced pull consumers with push consumers.
It's deprecated but it's the only way I found to have this working.
I put the example here if someone get the same issue.
(Feel free to propose a better solution if you have one)
I replaced
async listen() {
    const js = await this._client.Connection?.jetstream();
    if (!js) throw new Error("Jetstream Error");

    const consumer = await initConsumer(js, this._client.ServiceName, this.subject);
    const msgs = await consumer.consume();
    for await (const msg of msgs) {
      const data = JSONCodec().decode(msg.data)

      try {
        await this.onMessage(data, msg);
        msg.ack();
      } catch (err) {
        msg.nack();
      }
    }
  }

with
async listen() {
    const js = await this._client.Connection?.jetstream();
    if (!js) throw new Error("Jetstream Error");

    const options = consumerOpts()
      .ackExplicit()
      .consumerName(this._client.ServiceName)
      .deliverAll()
      .deliverGroup(this._client.ServiceName)
      .deliverTo(createInbox())
      .ackWait(1000)
      .durable(this._client.ServiceName)
      .queue(this._client.ServiceName);

    const subscription = await js.subscribe(this.subject, options); // js.subscribe IS DEPRECATED

    for await (const msg of subscription) {
      const data = parseMessage(msg);

      try {
        const details = await this.onMessage(data, msg);
        this.onAccept(msg, data, details);
      } catch (err) {
        this.onReject(msg, data, err);
      }
    }
  }

